# Creating Table with CC Exp Date - Oracle PL SQL

Tags: oracle, date, stored-procedures, credit-card

I'm trying to create a table with date constraint that will make the date value of MM/YY for credit card expiration date. When I try to create the below table I receive the error:

```
  CONSTRAINT exp_check CHECK TO_CHAR(exp_date,'MM/YY'),
                       *
  ERROR at line 19: 
  ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis 


 Create table Orders    
 (o_id int NOT NULL,
 c_id int NOT NULL,
 p_id int NOT NULL,
 s_id int NOT NULL,
 order_date date DEFAULT sysdate,
 o_qty number NOT NULL,
 order_total number NOT NULL,
 card_type varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
 cc_number varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
 exp_date date NOT NULL,
 shipping_date date,
 shipping_status varchar2(50) DEFAULT 'Not Shipped Yet',
  UNIQUE (o_ID, c_ID, p_ID),
  CONSTRAINT order_ID PRIMARY KEY (O_ID),
 CONSTRAINT fk_cust_id FOREIGN KEY (C_ID) REFERENCES customers(C_ID),
 CONSTRAINT fk_ship_id FOREIGN KEY (S_ID) REFERENCES shipping(S_ID),
 CONSTRAINT qty_check CHECK (o_qty >= 0),
 CONSTRAINT exp_check CHECK TO_CHAR(exp_date,'MM/YY'),
 CONSTRAINT s_check CHECK (shipping_status IN 
 ('Not shipped yet', 'Shipped', 'Delivered'))
 );
```

Once I'm able to create the table I will create a executed stored procedure that will execute the below:

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
  DECLARE
  i_result varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  place_order(2200,1,'Regular','VISA','1111-1111-2222-3333',11/19,1040,i_result);
 END;
```

Comment: `CHECK TO_CHAR(exp_date,'MM/YY'),` doesn't make sense. You need to compare the result of the `to_char()` call to _something_ (just as you did with the other constraints). Also: your parameter `11/19` is not a valid date. See the manual for details on how to write a correct `date` literal: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Answer (score 0):

A `date` always has a day. month, year, hour, minute, and second.  You could store a date that is midnight on the first of the month and validate that the `exp_date = trunc(exp_date, 'MM')`.  When you display the value to the user, you'd then use the `to_char` expression to display it in the format that you want.

Alternately, you could store a string in the format `MM/YY` and your check constraint could put various validations on that string (i.e. the first two characters are a number between 1 and 12, the fourth and fifth characters are a number between 15 and 25, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a DATE value in Oracle always has the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOURS, MINUTES, and SECONDS. I think what you want to do here is to store the last day/hour/minute/second of the expiration date in your EXP_DATE column, e.g. if expiration shown on the card is '07/19' you'd want to store 31-JUL-2019 23:59:59, which is the last possible second that the card is valid, in the EXP_DATE field. Then when you want to display the expiration date in its usual MM/YY format you just have to format it with TO_CHAR, e.g. `TO_CHAR(EXP_DATE, 'MM/YY')`.

Best of luck.